# Replace variable value

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
checked_ids = request_data["ids"]

for service_id in checked_ids:
    if service == "insertion-order"::
        IO.modify(id=service_id,data={"state":request_data["state"]},params={"advertiser_id": advertiser_id })
    if service == "line-item"::
        LI.modify(id=service_id,data={"state":request_data["state"]},params={"advertiser_id": advertiser_id })
    if service == "conversion-pixel":
        PIXEL.modify(id=service_id,data={"state":request_data["state"]},params={"advertiser_id": advertiser_id })
    if service == "segment-pixel":
        SEGMENT.modify(id=service_id,data={"state":request_data["state"]},params={"advertiser_id": advertiser_id })

return Response({"Success":"201"})
```

As you all can see I am doing same thing for all service is "insertion-order", "line-item" or etc, but only the first few line changes (i.e "IO","LI","PIXEL","SEGMENT") these are basically class instances called. I want to replace that with only one line such that only this ("IO","LI","PIXEL","SEGMENT") name changes i.e

```
names = {"insertion-order": IO, "line-item": LI, "conversion-pixel": PIXEl ...}
```

and later

```
names[service].modify(id=service_id, data={"state":request_data["state"]}, params={"advertiser_id": advertiser_id })
```

inplace of `name[service]` I want dynamic value like IO or LI etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a mapping between service name `insertion-order`, ... to `IO`, ...

```
service_mapping = {
    'insertion-order': IO,
    'line-item': LI,
    'conversion-pixel': PIXEL,
    'segment-pixel': SEGMENT,
}
```

And use the mapping to get class instance from service service_id.

```
checked_ids = request_data["ids"]
for service_id in checked_ids:
    srv = service_mapping[service_id]
    srv.modify(id=service_id,data={"state":request_data["state"]},params={"advertiser_id": advertiser_id })

return Response({"Success":"201"})
```

NOTE: You may need to handle unknown service id case.

```
for service_id in checked_ids:
    srv = service_mapping.get(service_id)
    if srv is None:
        # Unknown service_id!
        continue
    srv.modify(id=service_id,data={"state":request_data["state"]},params=
```